# While installing, stays copying files, stuck!

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have an old Dell desktop that is running windows XP home edition.
I've downloaded ubuntu and installed it straight from the iso file.
When I boot my computer I choose to run Ubuntu, simple,
Then it needs to install;
However, it gets to about 3 quarters of the way and just stays there
waiting doesn't do anything :/

Can anyone help me out? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should create a live usb or live cd to install ubuntu..if you have done so then rewrite the live media again, try reinstalling the system with the rewritten media

Comment: It worked like a charm :)
I used a program that the Ubuntu download page suggested to use to write onto flash drives
Did that then booted into the USB
And worked :)

Thank you very much!!

Comment: @AnthonyAD By the way before this what media did you use to install ubuntu??

Comment: I extract the iOS file then clicked on the installer, it seemed to work perfectly, and when id boot my computer, I'd have the option of choosing windows or Ubuntu. Once I'd choose Ubuntu, it would have to install, 3/4 of the way through the installation, it would ALWAYS get stuck on 'copying new files' /: so I tried burning it onto a flash disk, and then I installed it from it, I had to make 'USB' the first booting option in order to install Ubuntu through the flash drive, worked splendidly

Comment: actually this happend to me some 2 years ago that's why I recognized that this is the problem of the live media and this problem can only be solved by a flash drive or live usb because it is fast and quick